# What happens to persistent volume if the StatefulSet got deleted and re-created?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I made a Kafka and zookeeper as a statefulset and exposed Kafka to the outside of the cluster. However, whenever I try to delete the Kafka statefulset and re-create one, the data seemed to be gone? (when I tried to consume all the message using `kafkacat`, the old messages seemed to be gone) even if it is using the same PVC and PV. I am currently using EBS as my persistent volume.

Can someone explain to me what is happening to PV when I delete the statefulset? Please help me.

Comment: Delete the statefulsets and check if you can see the data in the ebs volume folder.

Comment: by default, deletion of STS  will not delete the underlying storage.

Comment: This diagram should help understand this topic better - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73534207/6563567

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behaviour , because the new statefulSet will create a new set of PVs and start over. ( if there is no other choice it can randomly land on old PVs as well , for example local volumes )

StatefulSet doesn't mean that kubernetes will remember what you were doing in some other old statefulset that u have deleted.

Statefulset means that if the pod is restarted or re-created for some reason, the same volume will be assigned to it. This doesn't mean that the volume will be assigned across the StatefulSets.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? It doesn't seem universally true.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably look at how the persistent volume is created.
If you run the command
`kubectl get pv`
you can see the `Reclaim policy`, if it is set to retain, then your volume will survive even when stateful set is deleted

Comment: the reclaim policy is set to retain. I guess whenever I tried to re-create or start again,  I saw it connects to existing pvc and pv but it seemed like all the previous data wiped out.

Comment: That should not be the case! Persistent volumes should be able to hold data even after deletion. My guess is when you recreate a stateful set it could be creating a new PV?

Comment: No, i think it's still using the same pv. maybe re-created Kafka cluster is not able to find the existing data?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your scenario is that you have a statefulset which has got a persistentvolumeclaim definition in it - or it is just referencing an existing volume - and you try to delete it.

In this case the persistent volume will stay there. Also the pvc won't disappear;

This is so that you can, if you wanted to, remount the same volume to a different statefulset pod - or an update of the previous one thereof.

If you want to delete the persistent volume you should delete the pvc and the buond PVs will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes default prevent deleting `PersistentVolumeClaims` and bounded `PersistentVolume` objects when you scaling `StatefulSet` down or deleting them.

Retaining `PersistentVolumeClaims` is the default behavior, but you can configure the `StatefulSet` to delete them via the `persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy` field.

This example shows part of `StatefulSet` manifest file, where retention policy causes deleting `PersistentVolumeClaim` when `StatefulSet` is scaled down, and retaining when `StatefulSet` is deleted.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: quiz
  spec:
    persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy:
      whenScaled: Delete
      whenDeleted: Retain
```

Make sure you have properly configured StatefulSet manifest and Kafka cluster.

NOTE

> If you want to delete a StatefulSet but keep the Pods and the
> PersistentVolumeClaims, you can use the --cascade=orphan option. In
> this case, the PersistentVolumeClaims will be preserved even if the
> retention policy is set to Delete.

[Marko Lukša "Kubernetes in Action, Second Edition"](https://www.manning.com/books/kubernetes-in-action-second-edition)

Comment: It seems helm chart does not allow this property , installation fails stating reason "not valid spec", detail Error :                                                                 
INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(StatefulSet.metadata): unknown field "spec" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta